# cadences with triads with two different notes

Tags: chords, cadence

Can a cadence consist of a triad with only 2 different notes?
Let's say I'm in `Fmaj` and want to include an imperfect cadence (`ii - V`):
`G - D - G` followed by `C - E - G`. The first triad has only two different notes (`G` and `D`), is this possible?

EDIT:
My question arose because I'm doing an exercise that requires writing a short melody ending in an imperfect cadence in `Fmaj`. I decided to use the `ii-V` cadence with the chords shown above. 
However, when I played the excerpt and finished with the "imperfect" cadence, it sounded a lot like a "perfect" cadence - the roots of the chords are `G` and `C` which are also in the perfect cadence in `Cmaj` and all notes are also present in the `Cmaj` scale. It certainly doesn't sound imperfect, which is why I was wondering if this would be allowed in music.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Like anything in music. There is no rule saying it can/cannot be done. The acid test is doing it, and listening. It will 'work' in some situations, but not in others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a start, if a chord has only two notes it isn't a triad.  It might IMPLY a particular triad, or be viewed as an incomplete triad.  But a triad has three notes.

The example you give is certainly possible.  In an F major context he bass notes - G, C - clearly outline a ii, V cadence all by themselves.  Omitting the 3rd of the first chord means it isn't fully defined as G major or G minor, but that doesn't negate the overall shape.

If we're talking about 'harmony exercise' SATB writing, we must consider whether dropping into 3 part texture for one chord is effective.  If we're writing in a more contrapuntal style, this sort of thing happens all the time.

Comment: Thank you, and you are right, it isn't really a triad. I've edited my question with additional information.

Answer (score 1):

For the cadence from `Gmin` to `Cmaj`:

Ommiting the **third** *(Bb)* of `Gmin` would make it `Gind` as it is *"indeterminate".* It is arguable whether a cadence can have the third ommitted because it makes it **extremely weak**. I could also find no cases of such a cadence. Furthermore, this  would mean that it is also not an **imperfect cadence**.

So while this is possible, its not very strong.

To avoid large jumps in the treble voicings, here is an example of how to do it in terms of voice leading:

[image: Voice leading]

- S: `D - C`
- A: `G - G`
- T: `D - E`
- B: `G - C`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it makes sense. I've edited my question with additional information.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible, like Tim says.

In early counterpoint it was even the rule that the final chord has no 3rd - in purpose to end in a perfect tonic. Even by Bach we can find still this practice.

There are 2 voice-canons missing the full harmony if sang without accompaniment like this one: youtube.com/watch?v=AGrsasgsFuQ

My question is: do we still speak of a cadence if there is only a single tune? but we could hear the chord progression I-IV6-V7-I ???

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've edited my question with additional information.